# PROLOG all combinations broken in three subsets

Tags: prolog

PROLOG newbie here. I  have the following list:

```
list([im204, im209, im210, im212, im214, im216, im217, im218]).
```

I need a `schedule(A,B,C)` predicate which will return all possible combinations/divsions of the elements above in three subsets A, B, C.

i.e:

```
?- schedule(A,B,C). 
A = [im204,im209,im210], 
B = [im212,im214,im216], 
C = [im217,im218] ; 
A = [im204,im209,im210], 
B = [im212,im214,im216], 
C = [im218,im217] ;
(...)
```

Can someone show me a simple implementation?

Comment: vote to reopen: not a double. the OP describes a partition of a list into 3 subsets of almost-same length, not the powerset as in the linked Q. @lurker

Comment: @WillNess I reopened because it is not simply a subset problem. But it is probably a duplicate of [Partition a set into n subsets using Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213714/partition-a-set-into-n-subsets-using-prolog). If I were able to re-vote to close, I would probably do so on that basis.

Comment: @lurker ah, this is closer, though still not quite the dupe: our subsets must all be of the same length (except for the last one). that's how I interpret the Q. or maybe it's not so... yes, I think I was mistaken there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [partition a set into n subsets using prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213714/partition-a-set-into-n-subsets-using-prolog)

Comment: @athageor either it is a duplicate, or the question is unclear. please clarify.

Comment: @WillNess yes, you're right. Probably a simple variant.

Comment: @lurker I changed your mind, by in the mean time, I changed mine. :) the Q is really unclear there.

Comment: I meant to say, but in the mean time you changed mine. @ lurker